# How to get decimal number out of a decrypted ecdhInfo field?

Tags: transaction-data

I have a known amount encoded in ecdhInfo. I can decrypt ecdhInfo according to this formula:

`amount = 8 byte encrypted amount XOR first 8 bytes of keccak("amount" || Hs(8aR||i))`

How can I get a decimal value out of this decrypted 64bit field? Or, what type of variable is it after decrypting? I am working in C and want to avoid floats.

Comment: "How can I get a decimal value out of this decrypted 64bit field?" <- The result *is* a decimal (base-10) value. Can you perhaps rephrase the question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is a 64 bit little endian unsigned integer.

If you're asking "how do I get a human amount out of an atomic unit number", divide by 1e12. cryptonote::print_money in the Monero source does this without using floating point operations (print the number, then manipulate the string).